# ActionController::TestCase inserts as UTC but select returns local time claiming it's UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, functional-testing, testunit

### TLDR

I have a RoR 3 app running against a PostgreSQL database that I am writing functional tests for. I noticed something peculiar which is causing a lot of testing issues: times are being returned from a select converted into my local time but purporting to be UTC.

Basically when I run my tests I create times like:

```
appointment_time = 1.day.from_now
```

Printing that out (`puts appointment_time`) outputs

> 2014-01-08 20:08:14 UTC

But when I do a select on that time (after inserting into the database) and print it out (`puts professional.appointment_time`) it shows

> 2014-01-08 15:08:14 UTC

Notice the difference there is 5 hours - that makes sense since I am in EST which is 5 hours behind UTC. But also notice the returned time claims to be in UTC - so it seems to be in EST but *thinks* it's in UTC!

This despite the fact that my `application.rb` file contains

```
# configure the default timezone for app and db
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'UTC'
```

### More info and code

Take these classes for example:

```
def Professional
  has_many :appointments
end

def Appointment
  belongs_to :professional
  attr_accessible :start_time
end
```

And the following snippet from `AppointmentController.rb`:

```
def create
  appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
  if (conflicts?(appointment))
    head :conflict
  else
    head :created
  end
end
```

In the `ProfessionalControllerTest` I have the following

```
test 'add conflicting appointment returns conflict' do
  professional = create(:professional)
  start_time = 1.day.from_now
  post :create, { professional_id: professional.id, appointment: { start_time: start_time } }
  puts "ORIGINAL TIME: #{start_time}"
  puts "SELECTED TIME: #{professional.appointments.first.start_time}"
  assert_response :success

  post :create, { professional_id: professional.id, appointment: { start_time: start_time } }
  assert_response :conflict
end
```

This test should pass because the first post to `create` will create an appointment which will then cause the second one to return a conflict because of the call to `conflicts?` but it fails because the second response is actually a success! The output here looks like:

> ORIGINAL TIME: 2014-01-08 20:08:14 UTC
>
> SELECTED TIME: 2014-01-08 15:08:14 UTC

Again, I am in EST which is 5 hours behind UTC so I could imagine seeing something like:

> 2014-01-08 15:08:14 EST

And that would make a lot of sense but it seems like somewhere the time is being converted to EST but still thinks it is UTC.

As mentioned, my application.rb has both these lines:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 0):

so i actually stumbled onto this today in a difference scenario. it turns out that

> config.active_record.default_timezone

defaults to `:local` if you pass it anything it doesn't understand. and it doesn't understand `UTC` which is what i was passing it! (bit of a discrepancy since `config.time_zone = "UTC"` works. to set it to UTC you gotta pass 'utc':

> config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc

so to be clear, my application.rb now contains:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```